# typescript factory function return type

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and I have been using composition api in my project, and have created heavy reusable services using the composition api pattern. like this :

```
export default function useX(){
  const b = computed(()=>{});
  function a(){}
  
  return {a,b};
}
```

I did not noticed that these computed properties are redefined every time I am calling `useX();`
Now I want to convert them to singleton services with minimal code change and no usage change.

So I decided to covert them to factory functions like this :

```
function factory(){
  const b = computed(()=>{});
  function a(){}
  
  return {a,b};
}
```

And created a helper class ti initiate them like this :

```
export declare type ServiceFactory = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown;

export default class SingletonServiceProvider {
  static Create(factory: ServiceFactory) {
    // TODO define proper type
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!factory.Instance) {
      // @ts-ignore
      factory.Instance = factory();
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    return factory.Instance;
  }
}
```

```
export default function useX() {
  return SingletonServiceProvider.Create(factory);
}
```

Now how do I tell the `Create` function that its return type should be whatever is returned from calling the `factory()` function ?

My IDE detects the type as `function factory(): {a: () => void, b: ComputedRef<void>}` and its good enough for me , but how can I tell this to the `Create` function ?

UPDTAE : This worked for now:

```
export default class SingletonServiceProvider {
  static Create<T>(factory: (...args: unknown[]) => T): T {
    // TODO define proper type
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!factory.Instance) {
      // @ts-ignore
      factory.Instance = factory();
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    return factory.Instance;
  }
}

export default function useX() {
  return SingletonServiceProvider.Create<ReturnType<typeof factory>>(factory);
}
```

Comment: I think you gave the best possible advice already to yourself in your code comment: `// TODO define proper type`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen but I don't wana define all the services types manually :(